# Postgres DB requires ownership to alter sequence

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions

From the Postgres server log, I keep seeing this error:

> ```
> 2015-07-07 20:04:59 EDT [22757]: [1-1] user=cvt_web,db=powerup_betz ERROR:  must be owner of relation seq_id_cti_data
> 2015-07-07 20:04:59 EDT [22757]: [2-1] user=cvt_web,db=powerup_betz STATEMENT:  ALTER SEQUENCE mla.SEQ_ID_CTI_DATA INCREMENT BY 50
> 2015-07-07 20:04:59 EDT [22757]: [3-1] user=cvt_web,db=powerup_betz ERROR:  must be owner of relation seq_id_cti_data_map
> 2015-07-07 20:04:59 EDT [22757]: [4-1] user=cvt_web,db=powerup_betz STATEMENT:  ALTER SEQUENCE mla.SEQ_ID_CTI_DATA_MAP INCREMENT BY 50
> ```

Apparently you need to be owner in order to alter the sequence, granting all privileges to `cvt_web` user doesn't work, only being an owner works. Can someone tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Superusers can do it, too.

Comment: Why is the app doing this? DDL shouldn't generally need to be run as a webapp's normal production user.

Comment: i tried using @GeneratedValue(strategy=“IDENTITY”) and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

From the postgresSQL [ALTER SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altersequence.html), you must be the owner of a sequence to use ALTER SEQUENCE statements. Granting USAGE privilege to a user only allows the use of currval and nextval functions.